# Why does this javascript only replace the html element a single time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I am learning SignalR and currently working on a recurring broadcast message to all clients.  My broadcast code works, but not as I expected it to.  The  `appmessage` is intended to simple display a broadcast message on all clients once it is transmitted.  The `appclock` function is intended to update the displayed clock data whenever that function is requested.  I was expecting to see an appending list, which I get, and also a regularly changing clock_data, which I only get once.

This is my javascript file:

```
$(function () {
    var hub = $.connection.broadcastHub;

    hub.client.appmessage = function (message) {
        $('#statusmessages').append($('<li/>').html(message));
    };

    hub.client.appclock = function (message) {
        $('#clock_data').replaceWith(message);
    };

    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

And the page's HTML:

```
<p id="clock_data">not set</p>

<p>Manually broadcast messages:</p>
<ul id="statusmessages"></ul>

@Section Scripts
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Statuses.js"></script>
End Section
```

The client javascript `appmessage` function consistently appends each new message to the list.

The client javascript `appclock` function changes the `<p>` element data the first time, but after that it doesn't change the element unless the page is refreshed.  When the page is refreshed, it changes the element once, and then stops updating again.

I'm thinking it has something to do with how I am invoking the hub connection, but I don't understand why the hub won't continue to update the clock_data element after the first time.

Comment: That is because `$('#clock_data')` has been replaced. It squarely do not exist anymore. What is the `message` content?

Comment: The message content was simply `even` or `odd` for the value of the minute because I'm just testing.  Do I then need to do my `replaceWith` replacing the entire element with opening and closing tags with its id parameter so it's setup for the next `.replaceWith`?

Comment: Using `.replaceWith()`, the target element is removed from the DOM and replaced with the `message`. I suggest you to try `.html(message)` instead... Which will place the message inside the element.

Comment: .html(message) didn't work, but .innerHTML(message) worked.  Why would that be?  Anyway, you certainly showed me where my understanding was deficient.  Thanks!  Obviously I'm also new to javascript, but I did get a book and am starting to read it. But thanks for your help.  Can't mark a comment as an answer, though.

Comment: `.innerHTML()` is the plain JS equivalent to jQuery's `.html()`. So it depends if you apply the method on a jQuery object or a DOM element. From the code you posted, I assumed it was a jQuery object. But if `.innerHTML()`, you have a plain JS DOM element... So I just can't submit an answer to your question... But you can answer yourself! (not a joke) ;)

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  Clearly I didn't understand there was a such a nuance in coding between jQuery objects and a DOM element.  But this code is from an MVC razor page, so I guess since it is a web page, it is by def following the DOM.  But I will keep this in mind as I'm studying JavaScript.